# PHP is not loading php_pdo module

Tags: php, windows, apache, pdo

When I'm trying to start my Apache web server (on Windows7/Apache2.2.22/PHP5.2.17) with php_pdo.dll (and php_pdo_mysql.dll) modules enabled in PHP, I'm receiving this error:

```
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\PHP\ext\php_pdo.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
```

I've set the extension path (correctly) in php.ini and all `.dll` files exist in \ext\ folder.

Comment: Are the modules in the correct version? Perhaps that are php 5.3 modules or a wrong compiler version.

Comment: I`m using php-5.2.17-Win32-VC6-x86.zip

Comment: Hmm ok and the extension path is really correct? And the php_pdo.dll is on that place?

Comment: extension_dir ="C:\PHP\ext", extension=php_curl.dll
extension=php_gd2.dll
extension=php_gettext.dll
extension=php_mbstring.dll
extension=php_mcrypt.dll
;extension=php_pdo.dll
;extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll

Comment: Yes ok and these files located in this place?

Comment: Yes, in C:\PHP\ext folder :)

Comment: Some people may also have to add `safe_mode=off` before this will work. I think it has to do with suExec and/or suPHP.

Answer (score 2):

uncomment `;extension=php_pdo.dll`

use `extension=php_pdo.dll` without semi colon ;

Edit 1:

also `extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll`

Comment: If I uncomment the    ;extension=php_pdo.dll I got the error described above.

Comment: @LarryCablistu also uncomment `;extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll`

Comment: hmm..wow...please check if you have `libmySQL.dll` file at your `mysql path\bin`

Comment: I don`t have mysql installed locally (I`m working with a remote Db). I`ve saved the    libmysql.dll file to apache/bin and c:\php\ directories

Comment: Are you sure you have using right `php.ini`? exist anywhere else?...and is it a new error?..it worked before?...any upgrading?

Comment: I`m using the correct php.ini file:    C:\Users\dude01>php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: C:\Windows
Loaded Configuration File:         C:\PHP\php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)

Comment: I already had all the suggested lines in my directory-level php.ini. I had to add `safe_mode=off` before it would work, though.

Answer (score 2):

I saved in apache/bin directory both php_pdo.dll and php_pdo_mysql.dll files and **it`s working now!** huh?!

Answer (score 1):

This problem was caused for me by having XAMPP/PHP 5.4 and a lone-install of PHP 5.1 on the same system.  XAMPP runs PHP under the C:\XAMPP\PHP folder by default, which is placed in the system path.  But my older (and forgotten) install of PHP 5.1.2, which requires php_pdo.dll, was also in the path (prog files) and it's php.exe was responding to command-line PHP statements.  So I was getting the old EXE running in the new folder structure, where there was no php_pdo.dll.

3 possible Solutions:
1. remove the old version of PHP.
2. change default programs for php (to point to xampp version).
3. explicitly specify the correct php for the project you are using.

I think any of those should work, but since I have no need for an older version of PHP I only tested the first one..   Hopefully this will give you somewhere to look, at least.